# While loop in R

Tags: r, while-loop

I am stuck with a problem in simulation. I have to find the rate of convergence of a certain statistic. But I am unable to get the program to run. In fact, whenever I am running it, R hangs.

```
n=100
eps=0.001
del=0.001
T=3.24
z=abs((T-3.14159)/T)
while((z*(n^del))>eps)
{
    del=del+0.001
}
del
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop, of course it hangs... You are increasing `del` (a dangerous name for a variable, by the way) and the expression in `while` will always be `>eps`.

Comment: Why are you using a loop for this? Simple arithmetic tells you the `del` value you're looking for -- `log(eps/z, n)`

Comment: @downvoters The answer might be obvious to the experienced R user, but not to the OP. The provided a reproducible example, so that makes the question better than a lot of other questions under the `[r]` tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comments. Very bad mistake this was..anyways, i got to know later than never..thanks :)

Comment: @sashkello sorry if i didnt get the pun..but why is it a dangerous name?(just out of curiosity) :)

Comment: @user2458552 Because it is a common name for a keyword (although it is not present in R), aka "delete". See, in your question it has been highlighted as if it is not an ordinary variable. It is not present in R, so it is OK, but just try to make variable names more descriptive and "safe", that is definitely not intersecting with anything in-built.

Comment: @sashkello Thank you for the valuable suggestion..will keep in mind next time i am writing some code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've constructed for yourself an "infinite loop," which can happen quite easily when using either `while` or `repeat` statements. See [R Language Definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Looping).

A `while` loop expects a condition that goes from being `TRUE` to `FALSE` at some iteration, for example:

```
> a <- 1
> while(a < 5) a <- a + 1
> a
[1] 5
```

This will increment the `a` value by one on each loop iteration and then stop the loop when `a==5`.

Looking at your loop:

```
while((z*(n^del))>eps)
{
    del=del+0.001
}
```

You increment the `del` value, but your logical statement `(z*(n^del))>eps` is `TRUE` from the very beginning of the code and remains `TRUE` forever because the lefthand side of the inequality is always increasing, thus the infinite loop.